# Authenticate Flask unit test client from another service (microservices architecture)?

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, microservices, python-unittest

## Problem:

So my problem is I have a Flask microservice want to implement the unit tests to it so when I start writing my test cases I found that I need to authenticate the unit test client because of some endpoints need authorization and here comes the problem the whole authentication system in another service this service all can do about the authentication is to validate the JWT token and get user ID from it so here is one of the `views.py`

```
from flask_restful import Resource

from common.decorators import authorize


class PointsView(Resource):
    decorators = [authorize]

    def get(self, user):
        result = {"points": user.active_points}
        return result
```

and authorize decorator from `decorators.py`

```
import flask
import jwt
from jwt.exceptions import DecodeError, InvalidSignatureError
from functools import wraps
from flask import request
from flask import current_app as app

from app import db
from common.models import User
from common.utils import generate_error_response

def authorize(f):
    """This decorator for validate the logged in user """

    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'Authorization' not in request.headers:
            return "Unable to log in with provided credentials.", 403

        raw_token = request.headers.get('Authorization')
        if raw_token[0:3] != 'JWT':
            return generate_error_response("Unable to log in with provided credentials.", 403)
        token = str.replace(str(raw_token), 'JWT ', '')
        try:
            data = jwt_decode_handler(token)
        except (DecodeError, InvalidSignatureError):
            return generate_error_response("Unable to log in with provided credentials.", 403)

        user = User.query.filter_by(id=int(data['user_id'])).first()
        return f(user, *args, **kwargs)

    return decorated_function
```

and the test case from `tests.py`

```
import unittest

from app import create_app, db
from common.models import User


class TestMixin(object):
    """
    Methods to help all or most Test Cases
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.user = None

    """ User Fixture for testing """

    def user_test_setup(self):
        self.user = User(
            username="user1",
            active_points=0
        )
        db.session.add(self.user)
        db.session.commit()

    def user_test_teardown(self):
        db.session.query(User).delete()
        db.session.commit()


class PointsTestCase(unittest.TestCase, TestMixin):
    """This class represents the points test case"""

    def setUp(self):
        """Define test variables and initialize app."""
        self.app = create_app("testing")
        self.client = self.app.test_client
        with self.app.app_context():
            self.user_test_setup()

    def test_get_points(self):
        """Test API can create a points (GET request)"""
        res = self.client().get('/user/points/')
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEquals(res.data, {"active_points": 0})

    def tearDown(self):
        with self.app.app_context():
            self.user_test_teardown()


# Make the tests conveniently executable
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

My authentication system work as the following:

1. Any service (include this one) request User service to get user JWT
   token
2. Any service take the JWT token decoded and get the user ID
   from it
3. Get the user object from the database by his ID

so I didn't know how to make the authentication flow in the test cases.

Comment: Did I understand properly? You have the `authorize` decorator and some endpoints that uses him. You need just skip `authorize` functionality for tests. Is it right?

Comment: Yes but `authorize` decorator return user object I want to not just skip it I want to kind of replace it with another decorator that's will return user from the test database

Comment: I understand. But why you can't find `user` inside `View`? Adding additional arguments inside a decorators may bring some magic.

Comment: Do you mean solution number 2 ?

Comment: Yes, right. I mean, `def get(self): user = User.query.filter_by(....)`

Comment: Can you explain more about your comment or write a full answer of what u think to solve the problme ?

Comment: yes. just give me a time. I have a lot of work at the moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is just an example. I skipped some little things such as `create_app`, `jwt.decode(token)` etc. I'm sure you can understand the main approach. Structure:

```
src
├── __init__.py # empty
├── app.py
└── auth_example.py
```

**app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask

from src.auth_example import current_identity, authorize

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
@authorize()
def main():
    """
    You can use flask_restful - doesn't matter
    Do here all what you need:
        user = User.query.filter_by(id=int(current_identity['user_id'])).first()
        etc..
    just demo - return current user_id
    """

    return current_identity['user_id']
```

**auth_example.py**:

```
from flask import request, _request_ctx_stack
from functools import wraps
from werkzeug.local import LocalProxy

current_identity = LocalProxy(lambda: getattr(_request_ctx_stack.top, 'current_identity', None))


def jwt_decode_handler(token):
    """
    just do here all what you need. Should return current user data
    :param str token:
    :return: dict
    """
    # return jwt.decode(token), but now - just demo
    raise Exception('just demo')


def authorize():
    def _authorize(f):

        @wraps(f)
        def __authorize(*args, **kwargs):
            if 'Authorization' not in request.headers:
                return "Unable to log in with provided credentials.", 403

            raw_token = request.headers.get('Authorization')
            if raw_token[0:3] != 'JWT':
                return "Unable to log in with provided credentials.", 403
            token = str.replace(str(raw_token), 'JWT ', '')
            try:
                # I don't know do you use Flask-JWT or not
                # this is doesn't matter - all what you need is just to mock jwt_decode_handler result 
                _request_ctx_stack.top.current_identity = jwt_decode_handler(token)
            except Exception:
                return "Unable to log in with provided credentials.", 403

            return f(*args, **kwargs)

        return __authorize
    return _authorize
```

Our test:

```
import unittest

from mock import patch

from src.app import app

app.app_context().push()


class TestExample(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_main_403(self):
        # just a demo that @authorize works fine
        result = app.test_client().get('/')
        self.assertEqual(result.status_code, 403)

    def test_main_ok(self):
        expected = '1'
        # we say that jwt_decode_handler will return {'user_id': '1'}
        patcher = patch('src.auth_example.jwt_decode_handler', return_value={'user_id': expected})
        patcher.start()
        result = app.test_client().get(
            '/',
            # send a header to skip errors in the __authorize
            headers={
                'Authorization': 'JWT=blabla',
            },
        )
        # as you can see current_identity['user_id'] is '1' (so, it was mocked in view)
        self.assertEqual(result.data, expected)
        patcher.stop()
```

So, in your case you need just mock `jwt_decode_handler`. Also I recommend do not add any additional arguments inside a decorators. It will be hard to debugging when you have more than two decorators with a different arguments, recursion, hard processing etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Danial sorry for taking a long time to test your answer I edit my question and add tests.py after I add your code but still not working could you take a look on it.

Comment: @FadyAlfred did you try my solution? you can customize all it.

Comment: I edit `tests.py` to match yours and I leave the authorize decorator as it is and test it but didn't work.

Comment: @FadyAlfred first of all: I see you have a mistake in mock (
`patch('common.decorators.authorize', fake_authorize).start()`). I also recommend removing the excess from the question. Just remove 2 solutions. Just create one endpoint, show `authorize` decorator, do not pass `User` into endpoint from decorator and add your full trace.

Comment: @FadyAlfred or tell me what exactly is not clear in my answer

Comment: Thank you very much I appreciate your answer and comments it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Could you create some mock tokens in your unit testing framework (that your decorator can actually decode like in a real request) and send them in with your test client? An example of how that might look can be seen here: https://github.com/vimalloc/flask-jwt-extended/blob/master/tests/test_view_decorators.py#L321

Comment: I don't want to add token creation logic to this service because of this logic exclusive only to user microservice all other services can decode only the token.

Comment: I can totally see why you wouldn’t want to do that, and that’s fair. That said, there is something to be said for testing the full and complete code path being taken in your micro services. If the token creation logic could be moved to a simple package that is used by the authentication service as well as all of your micro services (for testing only), there might be some value to that, to insure there isn’t a bug in your authentication decorator.