# Disable/Patch flask_of_oil OAuthFilter decorator for unittests

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, pytest, flask-restx

I have created a simple flask app that requires some end points to be called with a token bearer authentication. The opaque token is validated using the flask_of_oil OAuthFilter decorator with the proper client and secret combination.
This works as intended and properlly verifies the token for all requests with the @oauth.protect() decorator. However when running unittests, I need to disable the authentication routine.

I tried using something like unittest.mock.patch on top of the file to overwrite the oauth.protect decorator to a dummy lambda before importing the modules.

Is there a way to keep all functionality of app.py and just "removing" the  @oauth.protect() when in a testing scope?
I am fairly new to using Python for anything other than simple scripts so I am a bit in over my head and any pointers would be appreciated.

Here are simplified examples of the working app and my basic unittest setup:

**app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restx import Api, Resource
from flask_of_oil.oauth_filter import OAuthFilter

# consts
OAUTH_HOST = "https://check.my.token/oauth2/introspect"
OAUTH_CLIENT = "client"
OAUTH_SECRET = "--secret--"

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app=app)
oauth = OAuthFilter(verify_ssl=True)
namespace = api.namespace('api', description='AI & ML tools')


@namespace.route('/foo')
class Foo(Resource):
    @oauth.protect()  # decorator in question
    @api.response(200, 'Success')
    @api.response(401, 'Unauthorized')
    @api.response(500, 'Unexpected Error')
    def get(self):
        return {'bar': 'foo'}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    oauth.configure_with_opaque(OAUTH_HOST, OAUTH_CLIENT, OAUTH_SECRET)
    app.run()
```

**test_foo.py:**

```
from unittest.mock import patch
patch('main.app.oauth.protect', lambda x: x).start()

import pytest    
from main.app import app

@pytest.fixture
def client():
    with app.test_client() as client:
        yield client

def test_foo(client):
    response = client.get(path="/api/foo", follow_redirects=True)
    assert response.status_code == 200  # ==401
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured out a solution by using a more sophisticated pass-through decorator and mocking the flask_of_oil.OAuthFilter.protect directly instead of the one used and imported in my app. Credit goes to [Mock authentication decorator in unittesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47900727/mock-authentication-decorator-in-unittesting/47926195) which put me on the right track.

```
from functools import wraps
from unittest.mock import patch
import pytest

def mock_auth(_):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated_function
    return decorator


patch('flask_of_oil.OAuthFilter.protect', mock_auth).start()

from main.app import app

@pytest.fixture
def client():
    with app.test_client() as client:
        yield client

def test_foo(client):
    response = client.get(path="/api/foo", follow_redirects=True)
    assert response.status_code == 200  # passes now
```